# How do I dynamically determine if a Model class exist in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, model, google-cloud-datastore

I want to be able to take a dynamically created string, say "Pigeon" and determine at runtime whether Google App Engine has a Model class defined in this project named "Pigeon". If "Pigeon" is the name of a existant model class, I would like to then get a reference to the Pigeon class so defined.

Also, I don't want to use eval at all, since the dynamic string "Pigeon" in this case, comes from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two fairly easy ways to do this without relying on internal details:

Use the google.appengine.api.datastore API, like so:

```
from google.appengine.api import datastore

q = datastore.Query('EntityType')
if q.get(1):
  print "EntityType exists!"
```

The other option is to use the db.Expando class:

```
def GetEntityClass(entity_type):
  class Entity(db.Expando):
    @classmethod
    def kind(cls):
      return entity_type
  return Entity

cls = GetEntityClass('EntityType')
if cls.all().get():
  print "EntityType exists!"
```

The latter has the advantage that you can use GetEntityClass to generate an Expando class for any entity type, and interact with it the same way you would a normal class.

Answer (score 1):

You could try, although probably very, very bad practice:

```
def get_class_instance(nm) :
    try :
        return eval(nm+'()')
    except :
        return None
```

Also, to make that safer, you could give eval a locals hash: `eval(nm+'()', {'Pigeon':pigeon})`

I'm not sure if that would work, and it definitely has an issue: if there is a function called the value of `nm`, it would return that:

```
def Pigeon() :
    return "Pigeon"
print(get_class_instance('Pigeon')) # >> 'Pigeon'
```

**EDIT**: Another way of doing it is possibly (untested), if you know the module:
*(Sorry, I keep forgetting it's not obj.hasattr, its hasattr(obj)!)*

```
import models as m
def get_class_instance(nm) :
    if hasattr(m, nm) :
        return getattr(m, nm)()
    else : return None
```

**EDIT 2**: Yes, it does work! Woo!

Comment: Yeah, I should have also specified, I don't want to be using eval at all, since "Pigeon" could come from outside.

Comment: Affitmative. (Stupid comment min. length - I would have just said "OK.") :D

Comment: eval is completely unecessary here.

Comment: *was*. I forgot the second way when I first wrote the post, and left it there for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, looking through the source code and interweb, I found a undocumented method that seems to fit the bill.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

key = "ModelObject" #This is a dynamically generated string

klass = db.class_for_kind(key)
```

This method will throw a descriptive exception if the class does not exist, so you should probably catch it if the key string comes from the outside.